# How to set Postman tests with if else?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, postman

I want to have a json-schema validation test in Postman for both cases - positive and negative response.
There is my test in Postman.

```
positiveSchema = {there is a json-schema for positive response}

negativeSchema= {there is a json-schema for negative response}

if (pm.response.to.be.success) {
   pm.test("Positive response", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(positiveSchema);
});

    } else {

 pm.test("Negative response", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(negativeSchema);
});
    }
```

So, as I think it should work: if the response code is 2XX test checks the positive json-schema validation.
If the response code is not 2XX test checks the negative json-schema validation.

But I've got an error

> There was an error in evaluating the test script:  AssertionError: expected response code to be 2XX but found 500

What is wrong with my test?

Different patterns - if (pm.response.to.be.success) else if (pm.response.to.be.error).

Tiny validator doesn't work. But it's ok for my Postman version.

```
pm.test('Schema is valid', function () {
    pm.expect(tv4.validate(pm.response, negativeSchema)).to.be.true;
});
```

If I don't use "if else" - tests work. But I've got 1 passed and 1 failed tests.
I don't want to use such case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `pm.response.to.be.success` doesn't return boolean value, it's a test itself, therefore it throws error when a assertion fails.

To fix that, you can change `if` statement to

```js
if (pm.response.code === 200) {
   ...
}
```

if you want the response code belongs 2xx, then you can change the condition is something like that.

```js
if (200 <= pm.response.code &&  pm.response.code <= 299) {
   ...
}
```